# os.walk doesn't work correctly with unicode characters in path

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I want to walk through directory where subdirectories can contain non-ascii characters in names. In this case `os.walk` considers the subdirectory as a file. The examples below:

I have directory `test` with subdirectories: `asd`, `géocello`

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    print(root, dirs, files)
```

prints:

```
test ['asd'] ['geocello']
test\asd [] ['testfile.txt', '123.txt']
```

I run this code under Windows XP. On Linux everything is fine.
How to make Python to work with paths properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a *unicode* value for `directory`:

```
directory = u'C:/path/to/root'
```

Now `os.walk()` will use unicode paths throughout and Windows will handle testing for the `géocello` folder correctly.

Note that in that case, `root` and the values in the `dirs` and `files` lists will also be Unicode.